# How to create /etc/certificates/*.{cert,chain,concat,key}.pem files without reboot?

Tags: macos, security, keychain, osx-server, certificate

I am trying to move from Comodo to Let's Encrypt certificates on OS X Server (10.7).

Something in Apple's server.app and ServerAdmin.app is broken. I can see and select newly imported certificates in server.app but after a few seconds and re-opening the dialog the selected certificates are back to the original value. In "Server Admin" > Mail > Advanced tab I can select the new certificates and they stick. However the imap and smtp services still use the old certificate.

I see that for the old certificate there are 4 files in `/etc/certificates/`: `host.domain.tld.SHA1.{key,cert,chain,concat}.pem`

I know that the only the old certificate is in `/etc/certificates/` because SHA1 of the new certificate, looked up with:

```
$ openssl x509 -in host.domain.tld.cer -noout -fingerprint -sha1 | cut -f2 -d'=' | sed 's/://g'
```

, is showing a different SHA1.

#### Security import

According to [certbot4osx source code](https://gist.github.com/cyrilpic/4504527de3a7b08ed84e), it looks like the `security import host.domain.tld.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain` command should

1. import the certificate into the system keychain, and
2. create the `/etc/certificates/$1.$SHA_NEW.cert.pem`

#### Reboot

After a reboot only 3 files: `.cert`, `.chain` and `.concat`, are there in `/etc/certificates/`, not `.key`. Other times all 4 required files are in `/etc/certificates/` after the reboot.

#### CertsKeychainMonitor

I suspect that the CertsKeychainMonitor plugin is involved in `.pem` files creation. This as daemon started via `com.apple.UserEventAgent-System.plist`. Because Console lists at the second of the `.pem` file :

> UserEventAgent: CertsKeychainMonitor: ready to process keychain &
> timer events.

How to always get all 4 (Let's Encrypt) certificate files correctly in `/etc/certificates/` and **without reboot**?

Comment: According to the `.cert.pem` file creation time (the seconds), I suspect that `CertsKeychainMonitor` is responsable for creating these 4 `.pem` files. Log states at creation time: "_UserEventAgent: CertsKeychainMonitor: ready to process keychain & timer events._"

Comment: Two UserEventAgents are running, one as root user and one as logged in user.

Comment: Near the next certificate renewal November 17th, I will try: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserEventAgent-System.plist; sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserEventAgent-System.plist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Also import the .fullchain

Beside the .cer file also import the corresponding .fullchain file into the keychain, like

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/security -v import /Users/user/letsencrypt/fullchain.cer -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

## 2. Unload and load UserEventAgent-System

```
$ sudo /bin/launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserEventAgent-System.plist; sudo /bin/launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserEventAgent-System.plist
```

## 3. Wait

About 1-2 minutes for the 4 certificate files to correctly appear in `/etc/certificates/`